# Complicated sql query with variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

That's my query to get first `$count` rows for each city/subcategory combination

```
$contacts = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT c.*,
                 (@rn := IF(@cc = CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, subcategory_id), @rn + 1,
                            IF(@cc := CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, subcategory_id), 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as rn
          FROM (SELECT reg.title as region_title, cnt.title, cnt.city_id, cnt.id, cnt.catalog_id, cnt.address, cnt.phone, cnt.email, cnt.website,  cnt.subcategory_title, cnt.subcategory_id, cnt.manufacturer 
                FROM contacts as cnt
                LEFT JOIN regions as reg 
                ON cnt.city_id = reg.id 
                WHERE city_id IN (".implode(',', $regions).") AND 
                      subcategory_id IN (".implode(',', $categories).") 
                ORDER BY subcategory_title, city_id, title
               ) c CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT @cc := '', @rn := 0) params
         ) c
    WHERE rn <= $count");
```

And i'm using `$contacts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);` to group rows by reg.title

```
[ 
 ['City 1'] = > [ 
   [ contact 1 ],
   [ contact 2 ],
   ...
 ],
 ['City 2'] = > [ 
   [ contact 3 ],
   [ contact 4 ],
   ...
 ]
 ...
]
```

Now I need to upgrade that query but it's too complicated for me :( Selected rows must have unique contacts.catalog_id value.
How it can be done?

**UPD**
Here is a demo database - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac71d7/2

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: when we say "unique contacts.catalog_id" value, do we want to exclude from the result any and all rows where there is more than one row with a given `catalog_id`? Or do we just want to ensure that `catalog_id` isn't repeated in result? Or that catalog_id isn't repeated for a given `(city_id,subcategory_id)`?  Understanding and communicating the specification is 80% of the battle. And example data along with expected output would go a long ways towards illuminating the specification.

Comment: I have add an example data. We need unique catalog_id globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*We need unique catalog_id globally*"

To identify *unique* values of `catalog_id` in `contacts`, we could use a query like this:

```
   SELECT r.catalog_id
     FROM contacts r
    GROUP BY r.catalog_id
   HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

That says, for a given row in `contacts`, if the value of `catalog_id` matches `catalog_id` on *any other* row in `contacts`, that `catalog_id` will be excluded from the result.

If we want to restrict the original query to returning only those values of `catalog_id`, we could include this query as an inline view, and join that to rows in contacts with matching catalog_id.

---

```
                    FROM contacts cnt
  -- ------------
                    JOIN ( SELECT r.catalog_id
                             FROM contacts r
                            GROUP BY r.catalog_id
                           HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
                         ) s
                      ON s.catalog_id = cnt.catalog_id
  -- ------------
                    LEFT
                    JOIN regions reg
                      ON reg.id = cnt.city_id
```

---

**EDIT**

If the specification is interpreted differently, instead of meaning `catalog_id` must be *unique* in contacts, we mean that a `catalog_id` should not be repeated in the result...  we can use the same approach, but get single value of `id` from `contacts` for each `catalog_id`.  We could write a query like this:

```
   SELECT MAX(r.id) AS max_id
        , r.catalog_id
     FROM contacts r
    GROUP BY r.catalog_id
```

We could use MIN() aggregate in place of MAX(). The goal is to return a single `contacts.id` for each discrete value of `catalog_id`.

We can incorporate that into the query as an inline view, matching `max_id` from the inline view to the `id` from `contacts` table.

Something like this:

```
                    FROM contacts cnt
  -- ------------
                    JOIN ( SELECT MAX(r.id) AS max_id
                             FROM contacts r
                            WHERE ... 
                            GROUP BY r.catalog_id
                         ) s
                      ON s.max_id = cnt.id
  -- ------------
                    LEFT
                    JOIN regions reg
                      ON reg.id = cnt.city_id
```

We probably want to move the conditions in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query into that inline view. If we don't, then the `max_id` returned by the inline view might reference an row (`id`) in `contacts` that doesn't satisfy the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Relocating the `WHERE` conditions on `cnt` into the inline view ...

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM ( SELECT c.*
              , ( @rn := IF( @cc = CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, subcategory_id)
                           , @rn + 1
                           , IF( @cc := CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, subcategory_id),1,1)
                         )
                ) AS rn
           FROM ( SELECT reg.title AS region_title
                       , cnt.title
                       , cnt.city_id
                       , cnt.id
                       , cnt.catalog_id
                       , cnt.address
                       , cnt.phone
                       , cnt.email
                       , cnt.website
                       , cnt.category_title
                       , cnt.subcategory_title
                       , cnt.subcategory_id
                       , cnt.manufacturer
                    FROM contacts cnt
  -- --------------
                    JOIN ( SELECT MAX(r.id) AS max_id
                             FROM contacts r
                            WHERE r.city_id        IN ( ... ) 
                              AND r.subcategory_id IN ( ... )
                              AND r.email          IS NOT NULL
                              AND r.manufacturer   = 1
                            GROUP BY r.catalog_id
                         ) s
                      ON s.max_id = cnt.id
  -- --------------
                    LEFT
                    JOIN regions reg
                      ON reg.id = cnt.city_id
                   ORDER
                      BY cnt.category_title
                       , cnt.subcategory_title
                       , cnt.city_id
                       , cnt.title
                ) c
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT @cc := '', @rn := 0) i
       ) d
 WHERE d.rn <= 10
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this query a bit wrong. Look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e42628/5  Here should be 5 rows. Rows with catalog_id '4926348963357290 and '70000001018295015 should be included

Comment: catalog_id 4926348963357290 does not appear to satisfy the specification "unique catalog_id globally". As I said in my comment on the question, it really depends on what the specification is, how the specification is interpreted. My comment asked whether the specification meant that we should only return `catalog_id` values that are unique in contacts, or whether we are just ensuring a `catalog_id` value isn't repeated in the result. Again, this is where providing *example* of the expected result would help clarify the specification (in a way that "unique catalog_id globally" doesn't.)

Comment: sorry for the language barrier and thank you for help!